# Upgrade 4.5.6 > 4.6.1

Tags: upgrade

Running my upgrade stalls at the upgrade page. The buttons are not working and do nothing.

[image: I start the upgrade and it stalls on the first screen.]

According to the debugger in Firefox, there is an illegal character in noconflict.js and CRM.$ is not a function in runner.

[image: Javascript errors?]

Comment: now the critical bug in 4.6.1. Download 4.6.2!

Answer (score 2):

Solved via Facepunch. This time, my own.

http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=34797.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same error on a site of ours: -
CRM.$ is not a function

I've checked the .htaccess file and taken out any lines compressing Javascript or CSS.

It simply hangs on the upgrade screen.

Comment: Ok, I've found a fix!

The issue was the Drupal theme. I set the theme to Seven and this resolved my problem.